# Purolator Shipping Insurance "At Shipper's Risk" clause

Tags: liability, insurance, shipping

I shipped personal items from Canada to the US with Purolator. One package arrived significantly damaged (the delivery man also acknowledged and made note of this).

I purchased 1200$ worth of insurance, and I'm claiming 967$ with proof of invoices. The claims department is replying to me saying that personal effects are not covered, but are offering me 500$ as a kind gesture.

They had the following message:

> ...
>
> (vii) Articles not packaged in accordance with Purolator’s shipment
> acceptance policy (see “Shipment Acceptance Policy”).
>
> (viii) Articles not properly labelled in accordance with Purolator’s
> labelling requirements (see “Tendering
>
> Shipments to Purolator – Proper Labelling”).
>
> (ix) Seeds.
>
> --> (x) Household goods and personal effects.
>
> (xi) Articles designated as “Prohibited” in these Terms and Conditions
> but which have been tendered to Purolator and accepted for carriage
> (see “– Prohibited Articles”).
>
> Any “At Shipper’s Risk” Shipments accepted by Purolator travel on a
> “no-value” basis for the purpose of claims for loss or damage (i.e.,
> the Customer cannot increase Purolator’s liability by declaring a
> value for such Shipment on the face of the Bill of Lading or, in the
> case of Shipments prepared using an Automated Shipping System, in the
> designated user entry field).

I think they are liable. They clearly mishandled the package and I have invoices to prove the value of the goods that were damaged. I don't know what I should reply to this. I would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: Did you ship household goods that were not covered?

Comment: I shipped personal items (moved to the US). The damaged items/lost were: headphones, rice cooker, computer monitor. I have invoices for all of them.

Comment: I was under the impression that buying insurance would cover whatever was being shipped.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that company, but if they say no personal effects are covered than no personal effects are covered.

Comment: I'm not trying to be mean about it, but we can't change their policy. I'd take the money if I were you.

Comment: Hi Putvi, I don't think you're being mean about it. I was considering that, but there was something bothering me: why would they offer me any money if they thought they weren't obligated to? Perhaps their policy doesn't meet certain legal requirements to absolve them of all liability; so, I'd like to hear more opinions before I accept the money.

Comment: Their policy is what you agreed to. No one else sets their policy.

Comment: @Putvi: I'm not sure it's that simple - the question, to my mind, is whether that part of the policy is actually *enforceable*.  There seems to be a so-called "illusory coverage doctrine" that could come into play.  I found https://www.pennlawreview.com/print/?id=612 to be interesting reading (note there is a View Full Article button).

Comment: @NateEldredge Purolator or whatever it is is a Canadian company.

Comment: My guess the settlement offer is in lieu of figuring out how they took your money to insure the shipment.  Was there anything in the shipment (damaged or not) they would consider insurable for $1200?

Comment: It was all personal possessions.

Comment: Hello Klik!  Welcome to Law.SE.  Please read our tour page, located at the bottom of this page.